# How do I send this curl query via Titanium-Appcelerator

Tags: curl, http-headers, titanium, appcelerator

I am interacting with a web service in my Titanium Appcelerator Project (with oAuth 2) and I need to make an HTTP POST request. I am successfully making the command with curl like this:

```
curl https://api.website.com/oauth/ -i -d "param=value&nextparam=goeshere" -H "Authorization: Basic hashgoeshere"
```

That works. However when I try it in Appcelerator, none of my parameters get passed successfully, and since I haven't gotten that to work, I'm unsure whether I am passing the header correctly either. My titanium code is as follows:

```
xhr.validatesSecureCertificate = true;  
xhr.open("POST","https://api.website.com/oauth");

xhr.setTimeout(10000);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic hashgoeshere");

//unsure whether I need the next line or not. I don't in curl
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send('{"param":"value","nextparam":"goeshere"}');
```

I've debugged with the API server, and I'm getting the error that I would get if I sent no parameters, so obviously I'm doing something wrong. I just don't know what. Any help would be apprecaited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xhr.send` command should take a JavaScript object as the parameter, not a string:

```
xhr.send({ param :"value", nextparam :"goeshere"} );
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. Do you see any other problems with the code like that? It still is not sending properly and I'm getting the same response before even though I made that change.

Comment: Everything else looks OK.  Also try xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  You can also create the POST string yourself and see if that helps: xhr.send('param=value&nextparam=goeshere');

Comment: My build wasn't updating for some reason so I didn't see the updates. I fixed that, and now this works. Thanks!

Comment: Once you did a build for a device, and you want to continue developing, you need to remove the build